# Calling a function exactly after a setting State completes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call the function `getWeather` every time `setLocation()` is called.How can I achieve it?

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(`${IP_API_URL}`)
.then((res)=> res.json()
.then((data)=>{
  setLocation(data.country.name)
})
)
return getWeather(location)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setLocation will have a state right ???

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${IP_API_URL}`)
    .then((res) => res.json()
    .then((data) => {
      setLocation(data.country.name)
    })
  )
}, [])

//add another effect
useEffect(() => { 
  getWeather(location)
}, [location])
```